# Optimization - Leveraging Browser cache not working for .js and .png files

Tags: .htaccess, cache, javascript

I'm optimizing a website and I can't leverage browser caching for `.js` and `.png` files.

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf

<ifModule mod_expires>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 60 days"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
    <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|css|flv|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|js|pdf|png|svg|swf|tif|tiff)$">
        Header set Last-Modified "Mon, 31 Aug 2015 00:00:00 GMT"
    </FilesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Caching seems to work with other files but most analyzing tools show error messages like this:

> The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:
>
> ```
> /css/images/skin/chebuoni1.jpg
> /images/logo-footer-mobile.png
> /images/logo-footer.png
> /js/cheSlider.js
> /js/home-modal.js
> /js/home.js
> /js/jquery.bxslider.js
> /js/menu.js
> /js/slider-hover.js
> /analytics.js
> /ga.js
> /js/browser-fix.js
> /js/click-hover.js
> /js/cookiechoices.js
> /js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
> /js/lazysizes.min.js
> js/mobile-detect.js
> js/search.js
> ```

I tried adding and unsetting the `Last-Modified` header via `.htaccess` and various `.htaccess` configurations but nothing seems to happen. I have to mention my hosting provider is using CloudFlare on a virtual machine. What am I doing wrong?

Resources are being cached correctly in my browser but the analysis tools (tools.pingdom.com and google pagespeed insights) are telling my they re not

Comment: What are the HTTP response headers you see in the browser for these resources? (Add this information to your question.)

Comment: Do you need to direct it that "image/png" represents png files, or is that mapping built in? Suggest giving us the curl -i (ie show header) output for a type where headers are set correctly, and one where they're not.